# How to correctly import Proto files from different projects in C#?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I have 2 projects in my solution

/Common/Common.csproj
/Data/Data.csproj

I have a Proto file in my Data.csproj:

```
    <Protobuf Include=".\Protos\UserService.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
```

which looks like this:

```
service UserService {
  rpc AddUser (UserRequest) returns (SimpleResponse);
}
....
```

Now the SimpleReponse should be imported from the Common, so I created a common.proto in this project in the path /Common/Protos/common.proto and I want to import it:

import "common.proto";

service UserService {
rpc AddUser (UserRequest) returns (SimpleResponse);
}
....

Then Rider shows the SimpleResponse still red, as well as the common.proto import. When I Shortcut Space + . it will show me "add to proto imports" which I did.
So within the global settings the path is now correctly set - the proto and response are no longer red and I can F12 them to see them. When I now try to build, I still get errors:

[image]

I tried to add the path within the csproj

```
    <Protobuf Include="..\Common\Protos\common.proto"  
              Link="..\Common\Protos\common.proto" />
```

but still the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Importing Proto Files From Different Project was very tricky and I found this solution very great effort. So I want to share it with community

I was using MicroServices Architecture and I wanted my message ProtoFiles should in SharedProto Project and Used them in different projects

Let's Say I have message Proto files in SharedProto

```
SharedProto
--Protos
----company_dto.proto
----branch_dto.proto
---- ...
```

Content of company_dto.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "SharedProto.Protos";

package sharedproto.protos;
// *** DTO
message CompanyDto {
  int32 Id = 1;
  string Code = 2;
  string Name = 3;
  string Logo = 4;
  string Website = 5;
}
```

Content of SharedProto.csproj

```
....
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\company_dto.proto" GrpcServices="None">
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\branch_dto.proto" GrpcServices="None">
</ItemGroup>
....
```

Project Organization where I have Services Protos

```
Organization
...
--Protos
----company_rpc.proto
----branch_rpc.proto
...
```

I want to import `comapany_dto.proto` (which is a part of SharedProto Project) into `comapany_rpc.proto` (Which is part of Organization Project). Let's have look at `.csproj` file because all trick lies here:

Content of Organization.csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SharedProto\SharedProto.csproj">
      <GlobalPropertiesToRemove></GlobalPropertiesToRemove>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- DTOs -->
    <Protobuf Include="..\SharedProto\Protos\company_dto.proto" ProtoRoot=".." GrpcServices="None" Link="Protos\company_dto.proto" />
    
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\company_rpc.proto" AdditionalImportDirs="../SharedProto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you see above Organzation.csproj file, there are some really important points you need to understand to avoid `file not found error`  in case of import proto files from other projects.

`ProtoRoot=".."` and `Link="Protos\company_dto.proto"` after this, add this `AdditionalImportDirs="../SharedProto"` on that `<Protobuf Include=....` where you want to import your file. However after these setting you are able to import SharedProto file in your other projects in my case it was Organization project. Have a look

Content of company_rpc.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "Protos/company_dto.proto";

package organization.companyrpc;

// *** Rpc-Service

service CompanyRpcService {
  // Retrieve All
  rpc GetAllCompanies (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (GetCompanyListResponse){
    
  }
  ....

}
// Response: Retrieve All 
message GetCompanyListResponse {
  repeated sharedproto.protos.CompanyDto DtoRows = 1;
  string Message = 2;
}
```

If your see my `company_rpc.proto` file you will understand how I am importing it(`import "Protos/company_dto.proto";`) and how I am utilizing it (`sharedproto.protos.CompanyDto DtoRows`)

remember this `sharedproto.protos` came from a package name into company_dto.proto file

This above mention settings works for me in .net core grpc 2.60.0 and .net core 8